# Divergence of function $f(x,y,z)=e^{x}\sin(yz)$ is

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For a given function  $f(x,y,z)=e^{x}\sin(yz)$. Then divergence of $f(x,y,z)$ is

What i try ::

For a function $f(x,y,z)=<f_{1}(x,y,z),f_{2}(x,y,z),f_{3}(x,y,z)>$

Now we know that $$Div f=<\frac{d}{dx},\frac{d}{dy},\frac{d}{dz}>\cdot <f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}>$$

$$Div f=\frac{df_{1}}{dx}+\frac{df_{2}}{dy}+\frac{df_{3}}{dz}$$

But in my function given $f(x,y,z)=e^{x}\sin(yz)$

I have find $f_{x}=e^{x}\sin(yz)$

$f_{y}=ze^{x}\cos(yz)$ and $f_{z}=ye^{x}\cos(yz)$

Above function not in component form. Then how do i find Divergence . Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Divergence is a vector operator that acts on a vector field producing a scalar field. However, your $f$ here is a scalar field, not a vector field. In other words, the divergence of $f$, i.e. a scalar field, is not a defined operation.

Note: what you can calculate for scalar field is its gradient.